# Android app crash with putExtra

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to do a little app for myself and I can't do a putExtra on an intent, it crashes when I try to do it. After some search I can't find what I'm doing wrong, I'm pasting code who works perfectly and still crash

Main Activity Code to put extras :

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShinyCounter.class);

i.putExtra("pokemon", poke);
i.putExtra("method", meth);
i.putExtra("methodAbrev", methAbrev);
startActivity(i);
```

All variables comes from EditText like this :

```
String poke = pokeName.getText().toString();
```

And the get Extras on my ShinyCounter Activity :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

String pokeName = extras.getString("pokemon");
String method = extras.getString("method");
String methodAbrev = extras.getString("methodAbrev");
```

The error is : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference

Comment: what error you are getting..?

Comment: I'm getting the error : "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference"

Comment: where you call for `getIntent()` in your `ShinyCounterActivity` ?

Comment: Post more of the receiving code. You are probably doing it outside of a method

Comment: Oh it was that simple yes.. not the first time i got that kind of error. But how can i do if i want to use my extras on a Onclick event if i got them in the OnCreate method ?

Comment: I hope you 're not calling that method in your member declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like below in main activity

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityTwo.class);  
      i.putExtra("Value1", "Android ExplicitIntent");  
      // Set the request code to any code you like, you can identify the  
      // callback via this code  
      startActivity(i);
```

You can do something like below in ActivityTwo

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();  
String value1 = extras.getString("Value1");
```

Comment: Still the same error, I don't know why it says NullPointerException, even if i do a putExtra wiithout a variable to be sure it's not null that doesn't works

Comment: Make sure you are putting string only in putExtra and while retrieving taking string type variable only.If you have to put int and other variables so you have to use different putExtras methods and make sure you are doing operation in oncreate method of second activity after setContentView(R.layout.---------);

Comment: was doing it outside the oncreate that's why , thank you for the tips